# Win 10 software to organize downloaded images

Tags: images, knowledge-organization

When I download an image, I want to note its metadata, like the title, the author, the description, the accessed link. It would be nice to have the file name as the title of the image. Is there a way to do this efficiently or even automatically?

I use Win 10. It would also be nice to have a free app.

Answer (score 1):

exiftool can extract any metadata and apparently can also do renaming - see https://www.igoroseledko.com/renaming-files-with-exiftool.

Comment: this seems to only pertain to photographs taken by yourself. I would not work with a meme you download from the internet